# How to mark a persistence-unit as default in JPA (hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I read a few threads on setting a one out of n persistence-unit in JPA as default. But the usage of hibernate.default_schema seems to be vague.

However, I want to achieve the following.

- Have one default `<persistence-unit name="myMainPU"> ... </persistence-unit>`
- Have one or more additional `<persistence-unit name="auxilliaryPU"> ... </persistence-unit>`
- I don't want to annotate my injected EntityManagers with the name attribute. E.g. not like this `@Persistence(unitName="myMainPU")` for the default persistence unit. Should be simply like this `@Persistence`.
- I want to annotate my auxilliary PUs with the unitName attribute. E.g. `@Persistence(unitName="auxilliaryPU")`

How does one achive that? I use Hibernate 4+ and could also accept a proprietary solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such default option of "default pu".

What you could do is to use CDI and decide which PU you will use. I cannot see other way of doing it.

Comment: On WildFly you can define the default persistence unit by using the flag wildfly.jpa.default-unit

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring, try adding this before any other bean:

```
<bean id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"
    depends-on="myDefaultEntityManagerFactory, myAuxiliaryEntityManagerFactory, yetAnotherEntityManagerFactory">
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="my-default-PU" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Not using Spring. However, sure someone else profits! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wildfly as container, you can add the following property to persistence-unit which you consider as default. I assum other container may have such a property.

```
<property name="wildfly.jpa.default-unit" value="true" />
```